# run CMD as administrator in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cmd, administrator

I'm trying to execute a command prompt as administrator by using powershell. (like when you press right click on cmd icon and choose run as administrator).
what should I add to the following in order to do so?

```
& cmd.exe /c $VAR
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Somewhat obscurely, you must use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) with argument `-Verb RunAs` in order to launch an elevated process  (a process with administrative privileges) in PowerShell:

```
# The command to pass to cmd.exe /c
$var = 'echo hello world & pause'

# Start the process asynchronously, in a new window,
# as the current user with elevation (administrative rights).
# Note the need to pass the arguments to cmd.exe as an *array*.
Start-Process -Verb RunAs cmd.exe -Args '/c', $var
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without a window prompting asking yes or no. I mean I want to open the x64 native tools for VS cmd, but if I use  Start-Process -Verb RunAs "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" a windows pop up asking yes or no, as I need to use it in a jenkins pipeline it will need to be automatized, is there any parameter or workaround to do that?

Comment: @JesusFernandez, this confirmation dialog is an important security feature (UAC). While it is possible to deactivate it, doing so is a serious security risk. Do you really need to run your console as an administrator? If so, perhaps Jenkins itself can be configured to launch a process elevated, then you wouldn't need `Start-Process -Verb RunAs`.

Answer (score 0):

Type this command:

```
runas /noprofile /user:Administrator cmd
```

Then enter the Administrator password.

Comment: This only works with the built-in `Adminstrator` account, which is typically disabled for security reasons.
Otherwise, `runas.exe` doesn't support on-demand elevation from a non-elevated process for other accounts.
For instance, if your own account does have administrative privileges _in principle_, but your current shell is _not_ elevated,  `runas` offers no way launch another process as you _with_ elevation.

Comment: but this method asks me for a password, therefore I cannot use it in automated systems such as jenkins. Or is there any way to pass the password as a parameter or something like it?

Answer (score 0):

@Roei Givati - I just solved this one myself for Jenkins, in fact!
From a task scheduler set this command below (you get it from the nodes page on your jenkins dashboard), directly with the whole path, and give it the /K for the option in task scheduler. I also set the path as well, to be sure. Then you can use a non-interactive svc account to launch the process as a cmd file:

```
java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl https://jenkins-path/nts4/computer//slave-agent.jnlp -secret f7351fa6d6774765432111b704cfd777931144bb32c42 -workDir "driveletter:path\nts4"
```